# ERROR: Exception: Invalid argument: [Ljava.lang.Object;@7fcbe025 mySetEvent @ Try Calendar Event.gs:49. Need help pls

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I need help with my script. It's working fine when i tested it using 1 email in addGuests but when I added more email in the AddGuests it's now showing errors. (Exception: Invalid argument: [Ljava.lang.Object;@7fcbe025 mySetEvent)

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Set Reminder')
      .addItem('Create Cal Event and Send Email', 'mySetEvent')
      .addToUi();
}

function mySetEvent() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var selectedRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var numRows = selectedRange.getNumRows();
  var signups = selectedRange.getValues();
  var calendarIds = ['lventeria@kons.md']; // Add your calendar IDs here

  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    var eventTitle = signups[i][2] + ' ' + signups[i][3];
    var notes = signups[i][4] + '\n' + signups[i][5] + '\n' + signups[i][6];
    var columnHData = signups[i][7];

    if (eventTitle && notes && columnHData) {
      var startDate = new Date(signups[i][7]);
      var startTime = new Date(signups[i][8]);
      var startDateTime = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate(), startTime.getHours(), startTime.getMinutes(), 0);
      var endDateTime = new Date(startDateTime.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 1000)); // Changed event duration to 1 hour

      var addGuests = ['rieenteria@gmail.com', 'enteriamarilou@gmail.com', 'reyenteria@gmail.com']; // Add guest email addresses here

      var event = {
        description: notes,
        sendNotifications: true,
        guests: addGuests // Add guest email addresses here
      };

      var oneDayBefore = new Date(startDateTime.getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      event.reminders = {
        useDefault: false,
        overrides: [
          {
            method: 'email',
            minutes: 24 * 60
          }
        ]
      };

      for (var j = 0; j < calendarIds.length; j++) {
        var calendarId = calendarIds[j];
        var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
        eventCal.createEvent(eventTitle, startDateTime, endDateTime, event);

        var events = eventCal.getEvents(startDateTime, endDateTime, {search: eventTitle});
        if (events.length > 0) {
          var event = events[0];
          event.addEmailReminder(oneDayBefore);
          sendNotificationEmail(eventTitle, startDateTime, notes, columnHData, calendarId);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


function sendNotificationEmail(eventTitle, startDateTime, notes, columnHData, calendarId) {
  var recipientEmail = 'lventeria@kons.md'; // Set your email address here
  var ccEmails = ['rieenteria@gmail.com', 'enteriamarilou@gmail.com', 'reyenteria@gmail.com'];

  var titleParts = eventTitle ? eventTitle.split(' ') : [];
  var subject = 'BLAST REMINDER: ' + titleParts[0] + ' - ' + titleParts[1] + ' - ' + columnHData;

  var body = '**FOR BLASTING:**\n\n' +
             '**Channel and Promo:** ' + eventTitle + '\n' +
             '**Blasting Date and Time:** ' + startDateTime + '\n\n'  +
             '**Spiels and Segments:**\n' + notes;

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipientEmail,
    cc: ccEmails.join(','),
    subject: subject,
    body: body,
    options: {htmlBody: body}
  });

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert('Event Created', 'Event has been created in the calendar with ID: ' + calendarId, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}
```

I need help to make the script work
(Auto create an event - with guests and Auto send of email - with CC)

Answer (score 0):

The guests attribute should be a a comma-separated list of email addresses that should be added as guests, as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date,Object)). You are passing an array of e-mail addresses instead. You can join the array to get a comma-separated string of e-mail addresses.

```
var event = {
    description: notes,
    sendNotifications: true,
    guests: addGuests.join(','), // Add guest email addresses here
};
```

Comment: this solved my problem! thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem. You can mark this answer as the accepted answer.